# Implementation/explanation of the hub based labelling algorithm

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

I've found plethora of [papers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/HL-TR.pdf) describing the performance advantages and basic correctness proofs of the hub-based labelling shortest path algorithm.

However I'd like to implement the algorithm, and short of doing it from scratch don't see much of any other way.

Is there a resource or a project where such an algorithm is implemented, and or explained in detail?

My biggest problem is that I don't know much about the most practical datastructures (e.g. I'd be using a Fibonacci Heap, when it might be smarter to use something else, and I have very little information on the details of the algorithm.

Comment: Have you checked the paper by Abraham et al.? It should contain complete and detailed proofs.

Comment: Thank you, I've had a look, and it does shed some more light, but I was looking for a more practical description, ideally a functioning code framework.